# Why is my Chat not there?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Okay so someone already asked this question but I’m on an IPad. When ever I go on the server Hive my friend who is also on iPad can see the chat but I can’t. Even on my own worlds I can only see what my friend says in the world or server not what the other players say.i also can ONLY see what my friends that I know irl chat but not my long distance ones. Please help me I need it...

Comment: welcome to Arqade! first, what version of Pocket Edition are you on, on what iOS version? (you can find your iOS version by going into Settings > General > About, and it'll be "Version". you can find the Pocket Edition version by going to the app on the App Store and scrolling until you see "Version" and a number next to it.)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe bc you have the /gamerule commandblockoutput false
or it's off, or you are having some troubles with the internet

Comment: Well I tried typing in the gamerule command and it did not show up but my internet has been weird lately but I’ve had the same one for years but now it’s acting up. Please help me I miss seeing chat

Comment: Try A. Unpluging your router, wait 30 seconds then plug it back in B. Resetting  iit or talk to the people who own the type of internet box you have then send and angry complaint to them or D. Both reset and unplug it at the same time